# How to add BBC podcasts to Rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox, podcast

I copied link address from RSS feed here http://www.bbc.co.uk/podcasts/series/comedy. Then clicked ADD button in Rhythmbox podcast and added http://downloads.bbc.co.uk/podcasts/radio4/comedy/rss.xml

It gave the error that "The feed does not contain any downloadable items".

How to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: That is correct: at this moment, there are no episodes for this podcast. Try `http://downloads.bbc.co.uk/podcasts/radio4/fricomedy/rss.xml` for a podcast that currently does contain episodes. It is not a Rhythmbox problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're adding the wrong URL.  Here is what I did.

Opened Rhythmbox, clicked on Podcasts, and then right click choose New Podcast Feed, as shown in the image below.

[image]

Once you get the screen shown below, add the URL (http://www.bbc.co.uk/podcasts/series/comedy), and press Search.  That will get you all the feeds, and then just choose the one you want.

[image]

Comment: Which Rhythmbox version are you using? I'm using 2.96 and it just shows the "URL input" box when I click on New Podcast Feeds. (I don't see the search and subscribe buttons like you do) Anyway my problem got solved. Thanks.

Comment: I did it at a machine at work, and I'm not there, but its whatever comes with 13.04.  I called my colleague, and he checked it for me.  Its 2.98

Comment: Using http://www.bbc.co.uk/podcasts/series/comedy doesn't work in version 3.3.

What does work is to copy-paste the RSS URL (which can be found via a BBC podcast page's Subscribe button), which should give something like this:
http://podcasts.files.bbci.co.uk/p02pc9x6.rss