# Can't add New Yorker podcast to rhythmbox

Tags: rhythmbox, podcast

When I try to add http://www.newyorker.com/books’ podcast feed, I get this error:

> There was a problem adding this podcast: The feed does not contain any downloadable items.  Please verify the URL: http://www.newyorker.com/feed/books

Checking the feed, it looks fine....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
    xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
    xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/">
    <channel>
        <title>The New Yorker: Books &#038; Fiction</title>
        <link>http://www.newyorker.com/books</link>
        <description>Online version of the weekly magazine, with current articles, cartoons, blogs, audio, video, slide shows, an archive of articles and abstracts back to 1925.</description>
        <lastBuildDate>Wed, 06 Jan 2016 20:55:03 +0000</lastBuildDate>
        <language>en-US</language>
        <sy:updatePeriod>hourly</sy:updatePeriod>
        <sy:updateFrequency>1</sy:updateFrequency>
        <atom:link href="http://www.newyorker.com/feed/books" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
        <atom:link rel="hub" href="http://newyorker.superfeedr.com/" />
        <image>
            <url>http://www.newyorker.com/wp-content/assets/img/icon/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png</url>
            <title>The New Yorker: Books &#038; Fiction</title>
            <link>http://www.newyorker.com/books</link>
        </image>
        <item>
            <title>Life at One of England’s Last Tolstoyan Communes</title>
            <link>http://www.newyorker.com/books/page-turner/life-at-one-of-englands-last-tolstoyan-communes?mbid=rss</link>
            <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.newyorker.com/?p=3152111</guid>
            <dc:creator>Kelsey Osgood</dc:creator>
            <pubDate>Wed, 06 Jan 2016 12:00:37 +0000</pubDate>
            <description><![CDATA[<p class="descender">These days, the Brotherhood Church of Stapleton, one of Britain’s two remaining Tolstoyan communes, has just four residents, plus a friendly deaf cat, some chickens, and a large, lumbering cow. The commune can trace its history back more than a hundred years. In 1894, when Count Lev Nikolayevich Tolstoy was at the height of his fame, a group of acolytes known as the Croydon Brotherhood founded Purleigh, the first community in the United Kingdom governed by the principles laid out by the Russian novelist—who, following a mid-life moral crisis, had begun writing philosophical works in which he outlined his belief in Jesus Christ as a human prophet who preached pacifism, communal living, and a general distrust of governing bodies. Tolstoy quickly gained a cult-like following both at home and abroad—which he somewhat disapproved of, on the grounds that to follow a human leader was to ignore one’s own conscience. “To speak of ‘Tolstoyism,’ ” he wrote in a letter, “to seek guidance, to inquire about my solution of questions, is a great and gross error.” Still, people insisted on seeking guidance from him.</p>]]></description>
            <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p class="descender">These days, the Brotherhood Church of Stapleton, one of Britain’s two remaining Tolstoyan communes, has just four residents, plus a friendly deaf cat, some chickens, and a large, lumbering cow. The commune can trace its history back more than a hundred years. In 1894, when Count Lev Nikolayevich Tolstoy was at the height of his fame, a group of acolytes known as the Croydon Brotherhood founded Purleigh, the first community in the United Kingdom governed by the principles laid out by the Russian novelist—who, following a mid-life moral crisis, had begun writing philosophical works in which he outlined his belief in Jesus Christ as a human prophet who preached pacifism, communal living, and a general distrust of governing bodies. Tolstoy quickly gained a cult-like following both at home and abroad—which he somewhat disapproved of, on the grounds that to follow a human leader was to ignore one’s own conscience. “To speak of ‘Tolstoyism,’ ” he wrote in a letter, “to seek guidance, to inquire about my solution of questions, is a great and gross error.” Still, people insisted on seeking guidance from him.</p><p><a href="http://www.newyorker.com/books/page-turner/life-at-one-of-englands-last-tolstoyan-communes?mbid=rss">See the rest of the story at newyorker.com</a></p>Related:<br /><a href="http://www.newyorker.com/culture/cultural-comment/snubbing-margaret-thatchers-clothes">Snubbing Margaret Thatcher’s Clothes</a><br /><a href="http://www.newyorker.com/news/news-desk/the-corbyn-supremacy">The Corbyn Supremacy</a><br /><a href="http://www.newyorker.com/news/news-desk/hillary-clintons-resurrection">Hillary Clinton’s Resurrection</a><br />]]></content:encoded>
        </item>
```

---

My question seems a bit like [How to add BBC podcasts to Rhythmbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323307/how-to-add-bbc-podcasts-to-rhythmbox), but the answer there doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

When I open the XML file in Google Chrome, I'm being presented with this:

[image: XML Error]

Now, let's have a look at said line:

```
<title>The Tangled Cultural Roots of Dungeons & Dragons</title>
```

What immediately pops into my eyes is an unescaped ampersand, which should be written as `&amp;` instead. [Here](http://pastebin.com/raw/J9rZveLy)'s the fixed file. However, this will be of **no use** as you have to subscribe to the RSS from the original website to receive updates.

Let's see whether I can figure out how to tell them to fix their RSS.

Edit: I just sent a mail to the best address I managed to find, hopefully they'll fix it soon.

Comment: If this solved your question, please mark it as accepted by clicking the grey tick next to my answer. Btw. I haven't received any response from them yet, and it's still broken.

Comment: FWIW, the feed looks ok (today; "Holding the T" is the top result, then "Little Henry, Happy At Last", "My Last Day as a Surgeon", ……) in Firefox.

Comment: It didn't solve my problem. I still can't add the feed in Rhythmbox or `hpodder`.

Comment: Like I told you: **They** have to fix it. You can't do anything about it.

Comment: That was in response to your asking me for a ✓.